# Passing arguments in Azure Pipeline Triggers

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I've created a pipeline which needs to be triggered through an external process by a python script. My question is, how can I declare as parameters or variables all of the arguments i need to pass from the script? Imagine this is how I call the pipeline (this is already solved, not part of the question)

```
python script.py arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

How can I declare/take `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3` and `arg4` in the Azure Synapse Pipeline? I have not seen any dynamic content I can use on this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ***Custom activity*** in an ***Azure Synapse*** or Azure data factory pipeline to run ***python script***.

Go to ***Custom activity*** -> ***Setting*** and **add** dynamic content and also you can pass arguments inside dynamic content.

[image: Ref1]

For more details, refer to below links:

- [custom activities in an Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity)
- [Run Python scripts through Azure Data Factory using Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory)

Comment: thanks for answering! but I was looking to trigger the pipeline through a python script in my local pc and pass arguments